# IE9 Period Wrap Bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I just uncovered this little gem of an IE9 bug.  It seems that IE9 does not recognize a space preceding a period as a breaking point.  As in a list of domain or file extensions.  Open the following fiddle in IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/cssguru/nNnzM/1/

I tried using escape characters, but it didn't help. Any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: IE10 has the same issue, though i'm not sure it's a bug.  It may be deliberate.

Comment: I've found that adding "&nbsp;.web &nbsp;.blog &nbsp;.nyc ..." works but you end up with two spaces. This will work for what I am doing, but I think I'll leave the thread open and see if anyone else comes up with a cleaner fix. See http://jsfiddle.net/cssguru/nNnzM/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an annoying feature, but it is probably intentional and not regarded as a bug by the vendor. Instead, it is regarded as implementing [Unicode line breaking rules](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/unicode/linebr.html) (which are partly rather odd). According to those rules, the period (or FULL STOP as they call it) has line breaking class IS, infix numeric separator, and “When not used in a numeric context, infix separators are sentence-ending punctuation. Therefore they always prevent breaks before.”

To deal with such issues, it is probably best nowadays to insert U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE between a normal space and a period, e.g.

```
.web &#x200b;.shop &#x200b;.blog &#x200b;.nyc ...
```

U+200B is a control character that allows line breaks in a place where they would not otherwise be allowed.

Old IE versions (IE 6) may have difficulties with this, displaying a symbol of unrepresentable character in place of U+200B. An alternative method, the `<wbr>` tag, would not have this problem, but it seems that IE 8 and newer often fail to honor this age-old tag (perhaps because it never made its way to any standard, despite its usefulness).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the insightful response. I think I'm still favoring my "&nbsp;.web &nbsp;.shop ...", but I'll give you credit for the answer if I don't get a better response.

Comment: +1 One of the most informative answers I have seen around here.

Comment: I did a bit more testing and it looks like neither the &#x200b; or <wbr> work in IE8... http://jsfiddle.net/cssguru/nNnzM/17/

Comment: @AdamYoungers, in my tests `&#x200b;` works on IE 8, though I’m actually testing with IE 9 simulating (both quirks and standards mode). Did you test on actual IE 8? Both modes?

Comment: Yes, I tested with a full install.  I've been bitten to many times using IE9 to test older IE rendering engines. I now use XP-More with multiple virtuals setup to test each version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

I [added a declaration for word-wrap in this update to your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNnzM/2/), and that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: The problem with that is it breaks the word.  So ".apartments" becomes ".apart ments"